# Installing a custom version of a package with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.2",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue-clipboard": "0.0.1",
    "vue-dragula": "^2.0.0-alpha"
  }
}
```

I have a plugin that is not compatible with vuejs 2.2.4, so I really need to stick with 2.0.1, but when I make a `npm install`it install 2.2.4.

Why isn't it respecting versioning???

Comment: either use --exact flag or you can set the same `save-exact=true` to ~/.npmrc file to true :)

Comment: didn't work. I removed `znode_modules` folder, and ran `npm install --exact` and still get ├── vue@2.2.4 in results

Comment: --exact is when you are installing. You see the `^` symbol that denotes to install the latest version. Remove that and put the version that you want. Then run npm install. You need to put `--exact` if the package is not there in `package.json` and you are installing for first time :)

Comment: it work removing ^. You can put it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is symbol `^` in package.json file. That will automatically install the latest version of package. Now the proper way to get around this is adding

```
save-exact=true
```

in `~/.npmrc` which will automatically remove the `^` sign during install. This would prevent version change in future for installations of same package.